# За что отвечают 2 байта чанка IDAT и как их получить?

Tags: png

[image]

Как получить эти байты и за что они отвечают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это часть самих данный блока IDAT.
Все данные блока IDAT занимают судя по записи 226 байт (0xe2 перед IDAT).
Эти данные сжаты библиотекой zLib методом Deflate.
Нужно эти 226 байт начиная с указанных тобою отдать модулю/библиотеке zLib на распаковку.
После чего, в распакованных данных будут строки сканирования в количестве равном высоте (Height) изображения.
Длинна строки сканирования будет обусловлена:
1 байт - тип фильтрации от 0 до 4 (то-есть, существует 5 типов фильтров)
n байт - тип/размер семпла * битовая глубина * ширину изображения в пикселях

Советую вникнуть в RFC2083.